# assign drupal theme programmatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-themes

I know that we can assign a theme named `page-name.tpl.php` to a page called /page/ with the use of the theme engine.

How can i assign a theme to a template programmatically in drupal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use [Sections](http://drupal.org/project/sections) module?

c/p from project page:

> This module allows you to create
>   sections within your site. Each
>   section has an installed template,
>   theme or style attached to it.
>
> Sections are shown based on:
>
> - Node specific visibility settings
> - Role specific visibility settings
> - Page specific visibility settings (regexped paths)
> - Custom PHP visibility [snippets](http://drupal.org/node/64135)

Comment: Sections certainly provides access to this system, but it's just one of countless modules that approach this problem for one reason or another. Answering the question asked is @dobeerman and @ceejayoz.

Answer (score 4):

```
global $custom_theme;
$custom_theme = 'garland';
init_theme();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the global `$custom_theme` variable to change the theme.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--globals.php/global/custom_theme/6

```
global $custom_theme;
$custom_theme = 'garland';
```